# Google GPT - googletag.cmd queue re-order

Tags: google-dfp

Could somebody help me with the Google GPT googletag.cmd queue re-order issue?

(1) in the home HTML page, I have this:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() { defineSlot1(); });
googletag.cmd.push(function() { defineSlot2(); });
googletag.cmd.push(function() { defineSlot3(); });
googletag.cmd.push(function() { defineSlot4(); });
```

(2) in attached js, I dynamically added:

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() { defineSlot5(); });
```

(3) So right now in the googletag.cmd queue, the sequence like this:

```
[slot1, slot2, slot3, slot4, slot5];
```

My question is, how to move the **slot5** to the second place after **slot1**, like this:

```
[slot1, slot5, slot2, slot3, slot4];
```

In https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference,
googletag.commandArray only has push(f) method, and the googletag.cmd is not a standard array.

How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google GPT library is loaded in async mode and it initially defines `googletag.cmd` as a regular Array.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var googletag = googletag || {};
googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
(function() {
var gads = document.createElement('script');
gads.async = true;
gads.type = 'text/javascript';
var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
})();
</script>
```

When the main library gets downloaded (it occurs in parallel with page rendering) it converts the initially defined array into a custom object (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.CommandArray) so you indeed won’t be able to modify it.

Back to your question:

1. If you use 
   `googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest()` (https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_enableSingleRequest) all of your adslots will be queried and displayed on the first googletag.display(…) call.
2. If you don’t use `enableSingleRequest` an individual query will be sent each time you call `googletag.display(…)` for a particular ad slot regardless of its definition order

Considering p.1 and p.2 I don’t get why would you care the order of slots definition.
Anyway, if you really need it you might define your own queue variable

```
window.custom_cmd = [];
```

and use it instead of `googletag.cmd` throughout your page so it would look as follows:

```
custom_cmd.push(function() {
// regular defineSlot(…) calls
});
```

and then somewhere after your attached js file is loaded just

```
// reorder it or whatever else
…
// copy your queue into the regular queue
for (var i = 0; i < custom_cmd.length; i++) {
    googletag.cmd.push(custom_cmd[i]);
}
```

this code would trigger the ad calls